# Matching 2 strings in C#

Tags: c#, string-matching

I have 2 strings. These 2 strings can differ in size. I want to look at these 2 strings finding matching sequences. Once I find a change I want to print that word in Capital and then continue on in my string until I find another change and so on. I'm not sure how I would go about this I tried looking at words as a whole but I'm having issues with that. Basically I will have 2 string something like this `string one="This is a new value"` and `string two= "This This is a new also brand value`". I want go though each string from the start and find the matching sequences e.g. "This is" stop at string realise it has changed as string was added change it to upper case and then carry on. Expected output =`"THIS this is a new ALSO BRAND value "`

Some code I was trying. I don't think this is the right approach.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string one = "This is a new value";
            string two = "This This is a new also brand value";

            var coll = two.Split(' ').Select(p => one.Contains(p) ? p : p.ToUpperInvariant());

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", coll));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: In you first example of string one="This is text one" and string two= "This is string text two not string one" what is your expected output - "This is STRING text TWO NOT STRING one" or  "This is STRING TEXT TWO NOT STRING ONE". What would be your expected result if the two strings were swapped?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on some algorithms such as jaro-winkler https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro–Winkler_distance

Comment: @PaulF the second example is what i would expect.

Comment: @PaulF something like this `value1="This is a new Value";` `value2="This is also a new value";` `output="This is ALSO a new value"`

Comment: And also what should be the result if there is no match on anything : value1="This is a new Value"; value2="abc def ghi jkl mno";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? The description isn't fantastic, but judging by the answers this seems to be in the same ballpark, and it uses LINQ for less code and complication.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string one = "This is text one";
        string two = "This is string text two not string one";

        var coll = two.Split(' ').Select(p => one.Contains(p) ? p : p.ToUpperInvariant());

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", coll)); // This is STRING text TWO NOT STRING one
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can break this out to a separate method and pass your variables in as parameters.

Comment: This only words if one word is added eg one="this is a new word" two"this is also a new word" output "This is ALSO a new word". This word fine but if I have another word after also it doesn't work correctly. I want two"this word is also brand new" output "this word is ALSO BRAND new"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that issue with the code I posted, `string one = "this is a new word"; string two = "this word is also brand new"; //Output "this word is ALSO BRAND new"`

Comment: You're right it does work. But if I was to do some thing like this two="This This is new also brand value" output="This This is new ALSO BRAND value" Where it should be "This THIS is new ALSO BRAND value"

Comment: Could you update your question and provide full information on exactly what you expect, in what cases/scenarios, and any code that reproduces an issue where you're not receiving the output you expect? It seems to be a somewhat circular theme here with newer words being added.

Comment: I updated my code and what I expect the outcome to be

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to char array and compare chars one by one. You can use the following code i guess.

```
string one = "this is string one";
        string two = "this is string one or two";


        char[] oneChar = one.ToCharArray();
        char[] twoChar = two.ToCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        List<char> Diff = new List<char>();

        if (oneChar.Length > twoChar.Length)
        {
            foreach (char item in twoChar)
            {
                if (item != oneChar[index])
                    Diff.Add(item);

                index++;
            }

            for (int i = index; i < oneChar.Length; i++)
            {
                Diff.Add(oneChar[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (oneChar.Length < twoChar.Length)
        {
            foreach (char item in oneChar)
            {
                if (item != twoChar[index])
                    Diff.Add(twoChar[index]);

                index++;
            }

            for (int i = index; i < twoChar.Length; i++)
            {
                Diff.Add(twoChar[i]);
            }
        }
        else//equal length
        {
            foreach (char item in twoChar)
            {
                if (item != oneChar[index])
                    Diff.Add(item);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Diff.ToArray());//" or two"
```

Comment: I want to output something like this `value1="This is a new Value";` `value2="This is also a new value";` `output="This is ALSO a new value"`

Comment: Now your question means much more. First you should find difference as a describe and toUpper difference. 'if (item != oneChar[index])
                    item.toUpper();' But you need to be carefull because the difference char could be already an upper char. If this can be happen in your case it will be a problem.

Comment: Yea I didn't describe my questions very well initially. This can happen where the difference already may be an upper char. Could you please give me an example of how I could do this?

Comment: It depends on what you want and your scenarios's. For you "new","NEW","NeW","New" etc. are same or different ?Because difference is just lower case, uppercase. If these are similar for you then when you comparing chars and found them different, you should find out char case. Like onechar[i].isLower and decide to upper or lower case. But islower returns false if char is a number. So there is a problem and you want to solve it but i think your way is not so good. I assume you want to show somebody differences and so you choose to upper case, if you ask me use bold or change color is much better.

Comment: I want it to see the difference between value1="New" value2="new" output="NEW"

Comment: You can use the code which i answered.Just replace Diff.Add(item) -> item.toUpper() and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need? (Updated)

```
var value1 = "This is a new Value";
var value2 = "This is also a new value";
var separators = new[] { " " };
var value1Split = value1.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
var value2Split = value2.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
var result = new List<string>();
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
while (i < value1Split.Length && j < value2Split.Length)
{
    if (value1Split[i].Equals(value2Split[j], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        result.Add(value2Split[j]);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(value2Split[j].ToUpper());
        j++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Note that if for `value1="This is a new Value"` and `value2="This is also a new value"` output should be `"This is ALSO a new value"` than for `value1="This is text one"` and `value2="This is string text two not string one"` output will be `"This is STRING text TWO NOT STRING one"`, not `"This is STRING TEXT TWO NOT STRING ONE"` as you mentioned before.

Comment: That's nearly what I want. for example `value1="This is a new Value";` `value2="This is also a new value";` `output="This is ALSO a new value"`

Comment: You're getting closer. but when I put value1 = "This is a new value" value2 = "This is also a news value" the output should be "value2 = "This is ALSO a NEWS value"" however I go this instead  "This is ALSO a NEWS VALUE"