# Matching a sequence of 2 strings

Tags: c#

I have made a small application where I have an original string and an edited string. The original string is called "one" and my edited string is called "two". I want to go through each string and edits that have been made to a string and add the edited word in the original string in uppercase e.g. `Original "This is original"` `edited "This is edited"` output `("This is original EDITED")`. I want it to go through a string find the matching string and once it gets to a change to stop and change it caps and add the word to that position of the original string. This is what I have so far to find all the edited words in the string. My issue is joining the string. Expected output `"This This THIS is a new value VALUES"`

My code is as fallows

```
string one = "This is a new value";
        string two = "This This is a new values";
        int index = 0;
        var coll = two.Split(' ').Select(p => one.Contains(p) ? p : p.ToUpperInvariant());

        var col2 = two.Split(' ');
        var col1 = one.Split(' ');


        for (int i = 0; i < col1.Length; i++)
        {
            var a = two.IndexOf(col2[i].ToString(), index);
            if (col2[index].ToString()==col1[i].ToString())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(col2[index]);
            }
            else
            {




                Debug.WriteLine(col2[index].ToUpper());
                two.Insert(index, col1[i].ToString().ToUpper());
                //Debug.WriteLine(col1[i]);

                i--;

            }
            index++;
            if (index==col2.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", two));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Is this different to the seemingly same question you asked two days ago ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210366/matching-2-strings-in-c-sharp

Comment: @PaulF I asked the question a different way plus I'm attempting to code it a different way better way that takes into consideration if the string contains 2 of the same words etc

Comment: One of my original questions was what output is expected when there are no words in common : string1="This is a new Value"; string2="abc def ghi jkl mno"; should it be "This ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO is a new value" or "This ABC is DEF a GHI new KLM value MNO" or something else.

Comment: @PaulF It should be the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are solving the [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) problem. You have a sequence of items - words in your case - and you are trying to figure minimum number of changes made to the first sequence to reach the second sequence.

I would suggest you to follow algorithms in the Wikipedia article linked above and you will reach a very good implementation. These algorithms may look terrifying at first, but they are in fact very simple when you get into them.

Below is entire implementation in C#. It is based on dynamic programming and it reconstructs steps that lead from original string to the final string. Note that my solution is writing deleted words in square brackets. If you just wanted to skip deleted words, then avoid adding them to the output in the `ReconstructEdit()` method.

```
private static string CalculateMinimumEdit(string[] original, string[] final)
{
    int[,] costs = new int[original.Length + 1, final.Length + 1];

    // =, +, - or * for equal words, inserted, deleted or modified word
    char[,] resultOf = new char[original.Length + 1, final.Length + 1];

    // Set all costs to invalid values (mark all positions not reached)
    InitializeInvalidCosts(costs);

    // Empty sequences are equal and their edit costs is 0
    // This is setting the initial state for the following calculation
    resultOf[0, 0] = '=';
    costs[0, 0] = 0;

    for (int originalIndex = 0; originalIndex < original.Length + 1; originalIndex++)
    {
        for (int finalIndex = 0; finalIndex < final.Length + 1; finalIndex++)
        {
            SetDeleteCost(costs, resultOf, originalIndex, finalIndex);
            SetInsertCost(costs, resultOf, originalIndex, finalIndex);
            SetModifiedCost(costs, resultOf, originalIndex, finalIndex);
            SetEqualCost(costs, resultOf, originalIndex, finalIndex, original, final);
        }
    }

    return ReconstructEdit(costs, resultOf, original, final);
}

private static void InitializeInvalidCosts(int[,] costs)
{
    // Set all costs to negative values
    // That will indicate that none of the positions
    // in the costs matrix has been analyzed yet
    for (int i = 0; i < costs.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            costs[i, j] = -1;
        }
    }
}

private static void SetInsertCost(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf, 
                                    int originalIndex, int finalIndex)
{
    // You can always assume that the new word was inserted
    // Position in original sequence remains the same
    // Position in final sequence moves by one and that is the new word
    // Cost of this change is 1
    SetCostIfBetter(costs, resultOf, originalIndex, finalIndex + 1,
                    costs[originalIndex, finalIndex] + 1, '+');
}

private static void SetDeleteCost(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf,
                                    int originalIndex, int finalIndex)
{
    // You can always assume that one word was deleted from original sequence
    // Position in original sequence moves by one and that is the deleted word
    // Position in final sequence remains the same
    // Cost of this change is 1
    SetCostIfBetter(costs, resultOf, originalIndex + 1, finalIndex,
                    costs[originalIndex, finalIndex] + 1, '-');
}

private static void SetModifiedCost(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf,
                                    int originalIndex, int finalIndex)
{
    // You can always assume that one word was replaced with another
    // Both positions in original and final sequences move by one
    // That means that one word from input was consumed
    // and it was replaced by a new word from the final sequence
    // Cost of this change is 1
    SetCostIfBetter(costs, resultOf, originalIndex + 1, finalIndex + 1,
                    costs[originalIndex, finalIndex] + 1, '*');
}

private static void SetEqualCost(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf,
                                    int originalIndex, int finalIndex,
                                    string[] original, string[] final)
{
    // If incoming words in original and final sequence are the same
    // then you can take advantage and move to the next position
    // at no cost
    // Position in original sequence moves by 1
    // Position in final sequence moves by 1
    // Cost of this change is 0
    if (originalIndex < original.Length &&
        finalIndex < final.Length &&
        original[originalIndex] == final[finalIndex])
    {
        // Attempt to set new cost only if incoming words are equal
        SetCostIfBetter(costs, resultOf, originalIndex + 1, finalIndex + 1,
                        costs[originalIndex, finalIndex], '=');
    }
}

private static void SetCostIfBetter(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf,
                                    int originalIndex, int finalIndex,
                                    int cost, char operation)
{
    // If destination cost is not set (i.e. it is negative)
    // or destination cost is non-negative but new cost is lower than that
    // then the cost can be set to new value and 
    // new operation which has caused the change can be indicated
    if (IsBetterCost(costs, originalIndex, finalIndex, cost))
    {
        costs[originalIndex, finalIndex] = cost;
        resultOf[originalIndex, finalIndex] = operation;
    }
}

private static bool IsBetterCost(int[,] costs, int originalIndex, 
                                    int finalIndex, int cost)
{
    // New cost is better than existing cost if
    // either existing cost is negative (not set), 
    // or new cost is lower
    return
        originalIndex < costs.GetLength(0) && 
        finalIndex < costs.GetLength(1) &&
        (costs[originalIndex, finalIndex] < 0 ||
            cost < costs[originalIndex, finalIndex]);
}

private static string ReconstructEdit(int[,] costs, char[,] resultOf,
                                        string[] original, string[] final)
{
    string edit = string.Empty;

    int originalIndex = original.Length;
    int finalIndex = final.Length;

    string space = string.Empty;

    while (originalIndex > 0 || finalIndex > 0)
    {
        edit = space + edit;
        space = " ";

        char operation = resultOf[originalIndex, finalIndex];

        switch (operation)
        {
            case '=':
                originalIndex -= 1;
                finalIndex -= 1;
                edit = original[originalIndex] + edit;
                break;
            case '*':
                originalIndex -= 1;
                finalIndex -= 1;
                edit = final[finalIndex].ToUpper() + edit;
                break;
            case '+':
                finalIndex -= 1;
                edit = final[finalIndex].ToUpper() + edit;
                break;
            case '-':
                originalIndex -= 1;
                edit = "[" + original[originalIndex] + "]" + edit;
                break;
        }
    }

    return edit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. You're right it does look scary :P

Comment: I'm a novice programmer could you please help me out with this algorithm.

Comment: It's truly simple. Make a matrix where element at (i, j) shows the cost of translating first i elements of the first sequence into the first j elements of the second sequence. Figure relation between (i, j) and (i + 1, j), (i, j + 1) and (i + 1, j + 1) - which is eye-opening idea - and then populate the matrix iteratively. Finally, just read the optimal path leading to (n, m) and that's your optimal sequence of edits.Got it? :)

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind it but I'm not sure how I would go about coding it

Comment: I have added code which reconstructs minimum cost editing steps. I will probably publish this solution as an article on http://codinghelmet.com during next week, so you can take a look there for more explanations as well.